# How to restart a batch file after system Reboot

Tags: batch-file, selenium-grid

I have a batch file to start Selenium server on Windows 7. Is there a way to restart the batch file after system reboot automatically

Comment: Put batch file in 'startup' folder.  You can find in start menu. Not pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a task in the scheduler and add a trigger for system startup. Putting it in the startup folder will only run it when someone logs in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this action for a specific user, you could use the local Group Policy:

> 1.Open the Local Group Policy. **(Start > Run > gpedit.msc)**
>
> 2.In the console tree, click **Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**. The path is **User Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Logon/Logoff)** .
>
> 3.In the results pane, double-click **Logon** .
>
> 4.In the **Logon Properties** dialog box, click Add .
>
> 5.In the **Add a Script** dialog box, do the following:
>
> > ◦ In Script Name , type the path to the script, or click **Browse** to search for the script
> >     file in the Netlogon shared folder on the domain controller.
> >
> > ◦ In **Script Parameters** , type any parameters that you want, the same
> >     way as you would type them on the command line. For example, if your
> >     script includes parameters called //logo (display banner) and //I
> >     (interactive mode), type **//logo //I** .
>
> 6.In the **Logon Properties** dialog box, specify the options that you want:
>
> > ◦ **Logon Scripts for**  : Lists all the
> >     scripts that currently are assigned to the selected Group Policy
> >     object (GPO). If you assign multiple scripts, the scripts are
> >     processed in the order that you specify. To move a script up in the
> >     list, click it and then click Up . To move a script down in the list,
> >     click it and then click Down .
> >
> > ◦ **Add** : Opens the Add a Script dialog box, where you can specify any
> >     additional scripts to use.
> >
> > ◦ **Edit** : Opens the Edit Script dialog box, where you can modify script
> >     information, such as name and parameters.
> >
> > ◦ **Remove** : Removes the selected script from the Logon Scripts list.
> >
> > ◦ **Show Files** : Displays the script files that are stored in the
> >     selected GPO.> The path is User Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Logon/Logoff)
> >     .

[Microsoft - Assign User Logon Scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx)